# jQuery Click event on variable

Tags: jquery

I have two variables :

```
var Save = document.querySelector('[id$="btnSave"]');
var Cancel = document.querySelector('[id$="btnCancel"]');
```

How can I attach the same click event to the both ?

```
$('????').click(function () {
    sessionStorage.clear();
});
```

Comment: Hi Emma W, if I understand correct you want to execute same function on click of both id’s right?

Comment: jquery selector = querySelector. so you can do this `$('[id$="btnSave"]')` see this http://jsbin.com/pipegawulo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @plonknimbuzz not entirely accurate since jQuery has some of it's own pseudo selectors that aren't valid css selectors

Comment: @charlietfl yes you are right. i just give him simple comparison, since he is new in jquery. btw, ty for your note

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use comma separator `,` for multi selector, like :

```
$('[id$="btnSave"], [id$="btnCancel"]').click(function () {
    sessionStorage.clear();
});
```